# Don't show any data data

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my php and mysql code. It don't show any data . please tell me where is my error:

```
   <?php
    $ddaa = mysql_query("SELECT ref FROM users WHERE id='$uid'");
    $mallu2 = mysql_query("SELECT mallu FROM users WHERE id='$ddaa'");
    $result = mysql_fetch_array($mallu2);
    echo $result['mallu'];
    ?>
```

Comment: `$result` is an array.. therefore you need to use `print_r( $result['mallu'] );`

Comment: seems you don't fecth  $ddaa ..

Comment: If you want to link the two tables, look into JOIN rather than using two queries.

Comment: still have problem

Comment: tell the exact error where are you getting the error

Comment: Every time you use [the `mysql_`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)
 database extension in new code
 **[this happens](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-zCT6jizimfI/UjJ5UTb_BeI/AAAAAAAACgg/AS6XCd6aNdg/s1600/luna_getting_strangled.jpg)**
 it is deprecated and has been for years and is gone for ever in PHP7.
If you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli` database extensions and prepared statements.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: I dont see anywhere where you set `$uid` to a value

Comment: And `$ddaa` does not == ref please read the manual, we are not a substitute for doing some research for yourself

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Mysqli**,mysql is deprecated
a little example:

**conection to db test**

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'user', 'password', 'test');
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
 echo "Error: Errot on connection : \n";
    echo "Errno: " . $mysqli->connect_errno . "\n";
}
```

**// the query**

```
$sql = "SELECT ref FROM users WHERE id=$uid";
```

**//if don't have result**

```
if ($resultado->num_rows === 0) {
    echo "we can't find data with  $uid. try again !.";
    exit;
}
```

**//print the result**

```
while ($dato = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
echo $dato['ref'];
}
```

[Mysqli Php documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.examples-basic.php)